# Flutter navigate back to a page and refreshing the page

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have an app where i first check and grab some data once the first page is loaded. Here is the code from it. [Please note that I am developing the app on WEB]:

```
    return FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.wait([restaurantData, foodData, drinkData]),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
    //var state = Provider.of<QuizzState>(context);

    if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
      return Loader();
    } else if (snapshot.data![0]?.name == '') {
      return NoRestaurantPage();
    } else {
      return MainRestaurantPage(
        data1: snapshot.data![0]!,
        data2: snapshot.data![1]!,
       
      );
    }
  },
);
```

now, as you see, it returns the MainRestaurantPage which is a normal page. The problem comes when I open a new page from MainRestaurantPage. When I hit the back arrow to go back to the MainRestaurantPage, it refreshes the page because it goes again to the first page with the future builder and fetches the data again. How can I make it so that when I hit the back arrow on the new page, I go back to the MainRestaurantPage without it going to the first page and refreshing all the data.

Thank you very much for looking into this. If there is need for any more information, please ask

Update:

if I add a margin in a container before returning the page in the future builder, it returns the page with a margin on top, How can I make it so that it returns a new page instead of the current page with the widgeed (MainRestaurantPage) inside it

```
 return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: MainRestaurantPage(
            data1: snapshot.data![0]!,
            data2: snapshot.data![1]!,

  ););
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting the `Future.wait([restaurantData, foodData, drinkData]),` in the `future` property directly, you should be initializing it in a variable only open then use it:

```
// in the State object of that widget
late Future future;

@override   
initState() {
 super.initState();
 future = Future.wait([restaurantData, foodData, drinkData]),
}
```

the in the `FutureBuilder`, use it as this:

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: future, // apply it here
 // ....
)
```

Comment: it did not work..

Comment: i edited the question and added something so it may be  easier to understand what is going on